# Cordova iOS app display html page name as titile on alert

Tags: ios, cordova, cross-platform

Cordova iOS app display HTML file name as the title of the alert. I am using the following code to display the alert:

```
alert('This is alert.');
```

I want to remove HTML page name from the alert box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install cordova dialog plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Sample Usage:

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

Reference: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use the Cordova dialogs plugin.

Documentation here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/